$Z^*_{15}$ isomorphic to $Z_{4} \times Z_{2}$ how?
$Z^*_{15}$ isomorphic to $Z_{4} \times Z_{2}$ how?
According to a problem on Brilliant.org the above is true.
I looked at the tables
$ Z^*_{15} = \{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\} $
$ 2^8 = 1, $
$ 7^4 = 1, $
$ 11^4 = 1, $
$ 13^4 = 1, $
$ 8^2 = 1, $
$ 4^2 = 1, $
$ 14^2 = 1 $
and
$ Z_4 \times Z_2 = \{ (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (3,0), (3,1) \} $
$ (1,0)*4 = (0,0), $
$ (1,1)*4 = (0,0), $
$ (3,0)*4 = (0,0), $
$ (3,1)*4 = (0,0), $
$ (2,0)*2 = (0,0), $
$ (2,1)*2 = (0,0), $
$ (0,1)*2 = (0,0) $
There's no element of order 8 in $Z_4 \times Z_2$. How can 2 be mapped?
any hints?

$2^4=1$ in $Z_{15}^*$.

@paw88789 oh that makes sense, my bad.

Are you familiar with rings and Chinese Remainder Theorem? This problem is very easy to tackle then.

It helps to think about the structure of $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. It is abelian and generated by an element $a$ of order $4$ and an element $b$ of order $2$, where $b \neq a^2$ so that $b$ is not in the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$. Note: strictly speaking, these generators (and all elements of the product of groups) are pairs, so $a = (m, n)$ and $b = (r, s)$, where $m, r \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $n, s \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. But what matters is how these group elements interact with each other (the relations in the group), so it's useful and convenient to suppress the product structure in the notation when possible.
By considering the sizes of these sets, it's apparent that the group consists of the two (right) cosets: $\langle a \rangle \sqcup \langle a \rangle b$. Or thinking about it in terms of (left) cosets of $\langle b \rangle$:
$$
\langle b \rangle \sqcup a\langle b \rangle \sqcup a^2\langle b \rangle \sqcup a^3\langle b \rangle
$$
i.e., the elements are
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & a & a^2 & a^3 \\
b & ab & a^2b & a^3b
\end{array}
$$
So, we have to find analogous elements $a'$ and $b'$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}^*$. Then define the map $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_{15}^* \to \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ in the obvious way: $\varphi(a') = a$ and $\varphi(b') = b$. In order for this to be (0) well-defined, (1) a homomorphism, (2) injective, and (3) surjective, the elements $a'$ and $b'$ must satisfy precisely the same relations:

they commute: $a'b' = b'a'$,
they have appropriate orders: $(a')^4 = 1$ and $(a')^k \neq 1$ for $1 \leq k < 4$, and also $(b')^2 = 1$.

